# Ks test from Dagum distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have generated x numbers with Dagum distribution using inverse cdf method and now I want to run ks test but I constantly get this error:

```
Error using kstest (line 142)
CDF must define an increasing function of X.
```

This is my code:

```
N=20000;
a=5;
p=1;
b=1;
u=rand(1,N);
x=b*(u.^(-1/p)-1).^(-1/a);

cdf=(1+(x/b).^(-a)).^(-p);
X=0:length(x)-1;
h=kstest(x,[X' cdf']);
```

How should I run ks test with Dagum distribution'

Thank you!

Comment: can you show us the real code? If I copypaste that it has some ovbious errors (`a=5:`)?????????

Comment: Sorry.. I corrected...this is real code just parameters were with input function and I put real values...

Comment: I was doing according this ` H = kstest(X,CDF,ALPHA,TYPE)` if I put N-by-1 value a get this error Error using kstest (line 128)
Hypothesized CDF matrix must have 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CDF should be a  [`cumulative distribution function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function). The definition of a CDF inplies that its an increasing function, the only way it could decrease would be by having negative probabilities, which make no sense.

When you give  `kstest` a CDF, it should look something like this:

```
plot(X',cdf')
```

[image]

However, yours look like

[image]

Which is obviously wrong. Therefore the error you get is: `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function`, because it should, else it has no mathematical sense.

However, looking further, it looks like you have defined `X=0:length(x)-1;`. This makes no sense, as you are "rearanging" your `cdf` to point out to linear indexes instead of the real data. After some tests, I realised that if you  use `x` instead of `X`, then everything looks like its working.

Your `cdf` looks like:

[image]

and you can call `h=kstest(x,[x' cdf']);` without any problem.

As a side note, `cdf` is a MATLAB function, do not call a variable like that, or you will never be able to use the function!

Comment: Plus one for spotting `cdf` in there:)